CMake Error: Could NOT Find BLAS Using VCPKG and CMake on Windows
As a follow-up to this question, I am trying to set up a project using CMake with VCPKG on Windows to link the BLAS library. Despite following the instructions from the official VCPKG guide, I'm encountering an error when trying to find the BLAS library. Below are the relevant parts of my setup and the error message I received.
Environment:

Windows 10
CMake 3.26
Microsoft Visual Studio 2022
Intel oneAPI
VCPKG

Steps Followed:

Cloned and bootstrapped VCPKG:
git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg.git
cd vcpkg && bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
set "VCPKG_ROOT=C:\path\to\vcpkg"


Created CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(test Fortran)
set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} /Qipo /O3 /MP /Qdiag-disable:10448 /Qdiag-disable:warn")
find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)


Created CMakePresets.json:
{
  "version": 2,
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "default",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "$env{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
      }
    }
  ]
}


Executed the build script:
SET "PATH=C:\Windows\System32\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%VCPKG_ROOT%;"
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\setvars.bat"

RMDIR /S /Q build
DEL vcpkg.json vcpkg-configuration.json
vcpkg new --application
vcpkg add port blas
cmake --preset=default



Error Message:
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindBLAS.cmake:1346 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/share/blas/vcpkg-cmake-wrapper.cmake:7 (_find_package)
  C:/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:813 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package)

I also tried specifying the CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE directly in the command line (reference) and in CMakeLists.txt (reference), but neither approach resolved the issue.
Question:
How can I successfully find and link the BLAS library in this setup? What might I be missing or doing wrong?
P.S. I have also posted this question here on VCPKG Discord and here on CMake Discourse.

I tried with -DCMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_INIT="/names:lowercase /assume:underscore" and -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT="/names:lowercase /assume:underscore" and it did not work.
